# Titanium Alloy: XML preview

Tags: user-interface, titanium, titanium-alloy

Using Titanium Alloy, I'd like to have a glance on the view I'm editing without having to run the emulator each time a change a tag.

Is there a UI previewer? (or a UI designer)

I've tried Visual-UI but I can't make it work...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no visual UI designer for Titanium. You have to run your emulator to check your interface.

But while researching I found [TitaniumUI](http://titaniumui.com/). I don't know whether it is a good tool or not but at least there is another candidate you can try.